# My dynamically added table rows are not appearing in my app

Tags: android, button, layout, accelerometer, tablerow

I'm trying to create an app that has a start and stop button, which collects accelerometer data and displays the x, y, and z coordinates in tablerows. Each time the sensor detects a change, a row with the new set of coordinates should be added. Initially, I did not include buttons or an onPause() or onResume() method and the rows would be added dynamically. However, since there were so many rows being added, the application would freeze and drain my battery. As a result I added the onPause and onResume methods, in addition to a start and stop button for recording the data. Unfortunately, the buttons work but the rows of data stop changing after the screen is full of rows. I used the LogCat to check that rows are being added, and they are. I just don't know why they're not all appearing. My code is pasted below. The layout file is after the java file in the same block of code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    package com.explorer.extractor;

    //import packages

    import android.app.ActionBar;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.hardware.Sensor;
    import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
    import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
    import android.hardware.SensorManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TableLayout;
    import android.widget.TableRow;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
    import java.util.Calendar;


    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements SensorEventListener,OnClickListener {

        Button button1;
        Button button2;

        private SensorManager mSensorManager;
        Sensor accelerometer;

        private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
        private static final String FILENAME = "myFile.txt"; //file where data is written

        //layout variables
        TableLayout t1;
        TextView dataReading; //declare data text object
        Integer count = 0;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //initialize sensor manager
            mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
            //initialize accelerometer
            accelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
            //mSensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

            t1 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_table);
            button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

            button1.setOnClickListener(this);
            button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy){}

        /**onResume() registers the accelerometer for listening
         * to the events
         */
        protected void onResume(){
            super.onResume();
            mSensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        }

        protected void onPause(){
            super.onPause();
            mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        }

        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
           //if sensor status result is unreliable return
            if (event.accuracy == SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE){
                return;
            }

            Sensor sensor = event.sensor;

            //check sensor type
            if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
                //assign directions
                float x = event.values[0];
                float y = event.values[1];
                float z = event.values[2];

                try {
                    //write to text file the x, y, and z values each type a sensor detects change
                    writeToFile(Float.toString(x), Float.toString(y), Float.toString(z));
                    //return string of text file
                    String textFromFileString = readFromFile();
                    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
                    if(count%2!=0) {
                        tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    }
                    tr.setId(100 + count);
                    tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                    //show data read from file
                    dataReading = new TextView(this);
                    dataReading.setId(200 + count);
                    dataReading.setText(textFromFileString);
                    dataReading.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
                    dataReading.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    tr.addView(dataReading);
                    //finally add data to table row
                    t1.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    count++;
                    Log.i("LIMA","Add row. There are now " + t1.getChildCount()+"rows");
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:
                    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
            }
        }

        /**
         * writeToFile: writes data recordings of accelerometer to text file
         * @param x
         * @param y
         * @param z
         * @throws IOException
         */
        void writeToFile(String x, String y, String z) throws IOException {
            //get exact instance of time in which call to write is being made
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            //create string to print to text using values in parameter
            String s =  c.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) + " - " + "x: " + x + " y: " + y + " z: " + z + "\n";
            try {
                //append new string to file
               OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
                bw.write(s);
                bw.flush();
                bw.close();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "File write failed: " + e.toString());
            }
        }

        private String readFromFile(){
            String ret = "";
            try {
                //open text file to read from
                InputStream inputStream = openFileInput(FILENAME);
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                    String receiveString = "";
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        //continue appending to stringBuilder until you've reached the end of file
                        stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                    }
                    inputStream.close();
                    ret = stringBuilder.toString();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "File not found: " + e.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
            }
            return ret;
        }
    }



    Here is my layout file: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_table"
    android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:shrinkColumns="*"
android:stretchColumns="*">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tablerow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

         <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Start"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Stop"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question: you need to wrap the `TableLayout` in a `ScrollView`:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_table"
    ...
```

However, there are several problems with your code :-)

- Probably most serious: Don't perform any I/O on the main thread. I.e. don't read/write to files on the main/UI thread. There are many ways to create threads in Android, but two examples are `AsyncTask` and RxJava / RxAndroid. You can see this is a problem in your logcat log, like:

  ```
  I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
  ```
- It's not a good idea to log every single event received, since the accellerometer events are received very frequently when you use `SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST`. Even if you decrease the frequency, it's still not a good idea to add tens of thousands of entries to a UI list. You'd probably only want to show the last x number of entries and for UI purposes you wouldn't need more than say 1 or 2 entries per second or something like that, even if you want to log to a file more frequently.
- `TextView dataReading` should not be a member field - just declare it as a local variable where it's needed. Always declare variables as close as possible to where they are used.
- You are not using the `TableLayout` as a table, a regular `ListView` would suffice.
- Break the code up a bit. Look at the Single Responsibility Principle. Just as one random example, the file handling stuff can be moved out to a separate class.
- Why do you write the data to the text file and then read the same data from the file again? That's unnecessary I/O :-) You don't need to read the file at all. (Assuming you have a good reason to write to the file in the first place). And again remember: write to the file in a background thread using `AsyncTask` or some other threading mechanism.
- Minor: be consistent with your field naming, either use the "m" prefix or not, then stick to it :-)
- You're missing the `@Override` annotation in several places e.g. for `onResume` and `onPause`.

good luck!

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I just wanted to say how much I appreciated your help! As a beginner in android-development, you have no idea how nice it is when a pro breaks it down for you. Thanks again! :)